# Grouping based on previous and next ids in the same table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, group-by, apache-spark-sql, aggregate

How can the following grouping be created in Spark?

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(13, None,   17, 'data_a'),  # group 1
     (17,   13,   18, 'data_b'),  # group 1
     (18,   17, None, 'data_u'),  # group 1

     (14, None,   15, 'data_c'),  # group 2
     (15,   14,   16, 'data_d'),  # group 2
     (16,   15,   19, 'data_e'),  # group 2
     (19,   16,   22, 'data_f'),  # group 2
     (22,   19,   24, 'data_g'),  # group 2
     (24,   22, None, 'data_v'),  # group 2

     (20, None, None, 'data_w'),  # group 3

     (21, None,   23, 'data_h'),  # group 4
     (23,   21, None, 'data_x'),  # group 4
    ],
    ['id', 'previous_id', 'next_id', 'data']
)
```

Having the groups, it would be possible to create this desired result:

```
+------+------+------+
|id_min|id_max|  data|
+------+------+------+
|    13|    18|data_u|
|    14|    24|data_v|
|    20|    20|data_w|
|    21|    23|data_x|
+------+------+------+
```

There's no ID which would be common to every group. Also, group sizes differ, so a fixed number of self-joins is not really an option.

However, all the IDs form a kind of clusters - IDs cannot belong to other groups. Does this grouping require ML? How to do it?

Comment: Was this helpful or not at all?

Comment: @wwnde - I'm sorry I didn't have time yet to come back to this task. I really value your input. Thank you!!! I will not forget it and give you feedback when I come back, trust me :)

Answer (score 0):

A bit of Engineering I think. Lets try;

```
 new =(df.select('*',monotonically_increasing_id().alias('index'),*[when(df[x].isNull() ,1*col('id')).otherwise(0).alias(f"{x}_g") for x in df.drop('id','data').columns] )#create columns that normalize values we are interested in and also create an index for rainy days ahead
      
     .withColumn('grouper', sum('previous_id_g').over(Window.partitionBy().orderBy('index')))#Using index and normalized values create groups
      
      #Now that we have got it under hold group
      .groupby('grouper').agg(max('previous_id_g').alias('previous_id'),max('next_id_g').alias('next_id'),last('data').alias('data')).drop('grouper')
      
     ).show()

+-----------+-------+------+
|previous_id|next_id|  data|
+-----------+-------+------+
|         13|     18|data_u|
|         14|     24|data_v|
|         20|     20|data_w|
|         21|     23|data_x|
+-----------+-------+------+
```